# Dell Latitude e5570 wifi not working

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and I've got some isssues with my wifi.
Lan is working just fine, but since a few weeks I cannot ping through my wifi eventhough I'm connected to the network. But this is just at work. At home my wifi works just fine.

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:a4:71:c8:11:85
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-131-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=10.0.204.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:132 memory:e2100000-e2101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 28:f1:0e:2b:46:2c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=10.0.202.169 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:e2200000-e221ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwp0s20f0u2i12
       serial: 52:0a:43:cf:57:5a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=yes multicast=yes


~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.202.169 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.202.169 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.202.169 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5009ms
pipe 3

~$ifconfig    
br-d014c58f4909 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:26:ac:f4:62  
              inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:172.19.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

br-e0a7201ce52f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:99:b0:73:bf  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:af:04:2d:78  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:f1:0e:2b:46:2c  
          inet addr:10.0.202.169  Bcast:10.0.207.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2af1:eff:fe2b:462c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:45843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30767933 (30.7 MB)  TX bytes:3004989 (3.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:e2200000-e2220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:153287 (153.2 KB)  TX bytes:153287 (153.2 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:a4:71:c8:11:85  
          inet addr:10.0.204.40  Bcast:10.0.207.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e6a4:71ff:fec8:1185/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2726169 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:133610 (133.6 KB)

wwp0s20f0u2i12 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:0a:43:cf:57:5a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::500a:43ff:fecf:575a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:21384 (21.3 KB)


    ~$ rfkill list all
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


~$ ip route
    default via 10.0.200.1 dev enp0s31f6 
    default via 10.0.200.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
    10.0.200.0/21 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.202.169 
    10.0.200.0/21 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.204.40  metric 600 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev br-e0a7201ce52f  scope link  metric 1000 
    172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
    172.18.0.0/16 dev br-e0a7201ce52f  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.1 
    172.19.0.0/16 dev br-d014c58f4909  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
```

Comment: Possible lack of `default` route. What does `ip route` show?

Comment: I edited the output of `ip route` in the question